# Where to change the Woocommerce columns 4

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm trying to figure out where the string is to change the li class = "product-category product first" removing first,

of the div class = "woocommerce columns-4" ul class = "products columns-4

I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript.

```
$('.product-category').removeClass('first');
```

Comment: That's not what I was trying to figure out, I already knew this, but I don't want to make this change.

Comment: Ok, so you just want to remove "first" from the class, right?

Comment: Yes I want to remove "first", but directly from the file, not with a JavaScript, where can I go to make this change.
Because I first look at the browser's "page analysis" for the changes and then I want to change them, but then I don't know where to make the changes.

Comment: Got it. Perhaps it would help I we knew why you wanting to remove the class "first"? You don't want to directly edit the WooCommerce files. You will want to use a filter in your theme functions.php. Ideally in a child theme.

Comment: I did differently, through the CSS file, reducing the width and margin-right.
The question to remove class "First" is to get the 5 categories in line, because with the class "First" the fifth went to head.